# After merging, the file becomes dataframe. Then R does not allow me to use geom_sf

Tags: merge, sf, mapping, ggplot

I am merging attributes of provincical government spending to the China map.
I have a shp file and a csv file.
After `inner_join`, the class becomes dataframe.
Then R shows this error message: `"stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry"`

How do I change the merged file into geometry?

```
china_shp <- st_read("C:/Users/wenra/Box Sync/china_map/chn_admbnda_adm1_ocha.shp")
class(china_shp)
str(china_shp$ADM1_EN)

gdp_china<-readr::read_csv("./province_gdp.csv")
map<-inner_join(gdp_china,china_shp)
class(map)
ggplot(map)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=gdp))
```

Comment: You should perform the inner join with the `sf` object first: `map<-inner_join(china_shp, gdp_china)`

Comment: It works. But what's the difference? I thought inner_join only keep the ones in common.

Comment: Yes, but the resulting object inherits the class of the object on the left, so if you need a `sf` object you should place it on the left side